# Preventing multiple value in 3 column in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have get problem on this case, I don't know how to prevent multiple value in 3 column, I mean if the 3 column have multiple value it will not insert to database,for example I have **Krs** table where has data like this :

> | id | nim | nip | kode_mk
>    | 1  | 134 | 154 |  543

and laravel will ignore this data when someone insert data like this :

> nim=134,nip=154,kode_mk=543  laravel will not insert and give an
>   atttention

but laravel will accept if data like this :

> nim=1132,nip=154,kode_mk=543 laravel will accept and save to database
>   nim=134,nip=1984,kode_mk=543 laravel will accept and save to database
>   nim=1345,nip=154,kode_mk=543 laravel will accept and save to database

I have a table like this where I want prevent the data in the black circle:

[image]

this my **Krs.php** :

```
   protected $fillable = ['nim','nip','kode_mk','absen','uts','uas'];
protected $table = 'krs';

public function mahasiswas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Mahasiswa','id');
}

public function dosens(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Dosen','id');
}

public function makuls(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Matakuliah','id');
}
```

this my **KrsController.php** :

```
public function store(KrsRequest $request)
{

    $krs = new Krs([
        'nim' => $request->get('nim'),
        'nip' => $request->get('nip'),
        'kode_mk' => $request->get('kode_mk'),
        'absen' => $request->get('absen'),
        'uts' => $request->get('uts'),
        'uas' => $request->get('uas')
    ]);

    if ($krs->save()) {
        session()->flash('status','done_all');
        session()->flash('pesan','Data berhasil disimpan');
    }else{
        session()->flash('status','clear');
        session()->flash('pesan','Data gagal disimpan');
    }

    return redirect('Akademik/Krs/create');
}
```

I don't know how to explain it in english , sorry for my bad grammar

**EDIT 1 Table Structure**

[image]

Comment: Give prevention from database. Give combine-unique key to `nim,  nip and  kode_mk`

Comment: how to do that? can be more specific? sorry, i am new in laravel..

Answer (score 0):

In your Krs migration, set the field to require the value to be unique.  For example:

```
$table->string('kode_mk')->unique();
```